# How to allow wild card or other validation in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i have a input filed which i am validating using jquery

i am trying to allowing it wild card or some validation like allowing 10 digits.

When user input * as input there should be no other validation. if user not entered * there other should work

i have created a method as

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("exactlength", function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.length == param;
});
```

Ether * or digits with fixed lenght.

Comment: please clear your question ..more.

Comment: you can just do indexOf for the the * part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `string.Match` and JavaScript regular expressions:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html